# How to make registered users data sticky, and save it to Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

There are so many components out there, I'm not sure which one to use for this.

- I need registered members to be able to come back and edit some of
  the custom profile information that I have -- its a 4 page
  questionnaire with 10 questions on each page, quite long.
- the form needs to save form fields if user decides to leave (e.g. fills out
  only page 2 of 3).
- users can come back and complete the form, and see a summary of their responses   everything needs to be dumped in a Google Spreadsheet

I'm mostly seeking advice about a component or general direction I should pursue this -- is it a form component, or a social network-like component.

I've tried RS Forms Pro and while very powerful for form design it can't do google spreadsheet integration out of the box and conditionals are rather rudimentary.

Comment: Welcome to Joomla StackExchange. When asking a question, please add some information about what you have tried (some of the `many components out there`?), and why it didn't work. Simply asking what component can do X or Y is not a good question.

Answer (score 3):

ChronoForms or RSForms Pro are the two top form generation components.   I would go with ChronoForms as you don't need part for advance features like you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes! RS Form Pro was my first choice too. However, I was sad to find out that it couldn't do some of the most important things that I needed, with RSFP conditionals are basic, anything else other than the basic form features requires advanced scripting/PHP. There is no Google Spreadsheet integration, and for some reason in this day and age RS Form Pro forms aren't sticky -- entered info on page-1 of a form is not saved if user(s) exist the survey/form. Its a great form building component though, it just doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The features you are talking about are really beyond the scope of a form component. The sticky requirement moves to the realm of an application.

You might try using Fabrik to build the form you want, which will give you much more functionality. In any case, you will have to do some level of programming to accomplish what you're looking for.

You might also try breaking your forms into smaller forms and have them be sequential. That would make users more likely to complete enough of them before leaving.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if I need CCK or form-builder. Good pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[BreezingForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/8001) has an option to create sticky forms (for registered users). I'm not sure if the free version has this option, but it appears it does.

To create a sticky form that keeps the values filled out so far, in the menuitem of the form you have a option called "Submission editable by user" . If activated it should prefill the form with any saved data.

As for creating Google spreadsheets, I haven't tried myself, but it appears to be possible, check this link: http://crosstec.de/en/blog/entry/11-google-drive-spreadsheets-with-joomla-and-breezing-forms.html

[image: Google Integration]

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: BF can *not* make forms sticky. I have lifetime subscription with BF. Great support, great guys, COM has a lot of potential, but it can't create sticky forms at this time.

Comment: Sticky form == save form progress so far, not on on-submit-only. BF comes close though...